# Can conditional formatting reference other sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I needed to check which indexes exist on another sheet.
So for the `A:A` range, I made conditional formatting with the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF('Other Sheet'!A:A;A1)
```

That had a red error outline.
Then I filled column `X` with `='Other Sheet'!A:A` and used the formula

```
=COUNTIF(X:X;A1)
```

It worked instantly.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can, but you need to wrap it in **`INDIRECT`**:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Other Sheet'!A:A"); A1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you clarify why it only works this way? Are there other contexts only `INDIRECT` will work? I thought it was dynamic (from string) but still worked in the current context. This breaks that assumption.

Comment: this is only conditional formatting specific. not sure if its somewhere mentioned at google sheets help pages tho, but it works only if you use indirect to reference another sheet's range...

Comment: Alright, sounds like a bug :D